# Obscuring a links url

Tags: .net

Please pardon my ignorance. I'm looking for a point in the right direction.

I have a page with some (pdf)download links.
If I click the link a pdf will open in a new page.
I can see the folder the pdf resides on the server.
If I guess at other filenames in the same folder, maybe I can get lucky.
Some of the files are private so I don't want the user to get a hint from the url.
How can I obscure this infomation?
We are running .net 2 on the backend. Could I call a method and get the file to open?

Any help appreciated. I'm not sure what to search on to get me started.

Thanks

We have  a .Net 2 backend.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could associate each PDF file with a guid in your database, then you could create one page, DownloadPdf.aspx, and pass it the guid to locate the right file on your filesystem, and render it:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile(physicalPathToFile);
Response.End();
```

**EDIT**

If you want to give the user the ability to download the pdf, you could add the following line, before Response.End:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
```

Where filename could be the non-obscure name of the physical file (or any name you want to give it).

Comment: Better yet, rename the file to guid, and keep the original filename inside the database. This way you guarantee unique file name, and you can even have a basic file versioning.

Answer (score 1):

D.'s post is 100% correct, you can go one step further and save the file with a .resources extension therefore IIS would never directly serve the filE.

Comment: +1. that's an excellent point, although the same could be achieved by storing the files in app_data, right? that way you wouldn't have to distort the file type (handy for, say, when you're browsing the server remotely as an admin, or when you just want to know what type of content you're dealing with)

Comment: Yes, I believe that would be the case as well.